# Python 3.6 installing statsmodels failed with exit status 127

Tags: python, statsmodels

Trying to install statsmodels via `pip install statsmodels`. I am using Win10 and Python 3.6. I already installed NumPy, SciPy, Pandas and all the other dependencies. I have Visual Studio Community 2017 installed with C++ and Python related stuff.
I get this error:

```
    ...

    building 'statsmodels.tsa.kalmanf.kalman_loglike' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\statsmodels
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\statsmodels\tsa
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\statsmodels\tsa\kalmanf
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Istatsmodels/src -I"c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"c:\program files\python36\include" -I"c:\program files\python36\include" /Tcstatsmodels/tsa/kalmanf/kalman_loglike.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\statsmodels/tsa/kalmanf/kalman_loglike.obj

    error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Istatsmodels/src -I"c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"c:\program files\python36\include" -I"c:\program files\python36\include" /Tcstatsmodels/tsa/kalmanf/kalman_loglike.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\statsmodels/tsa/kalmanf/kalman_loglike.obj" failed with exit status 127

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files\python36\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-7jsmv60z\\statsmodels\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-kpya7eq2-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7jsmv60z\statsmodels\
```

What caught my attention was the "failed with exit status 127" part, but I couldn't find anything useful related to this.

Why is this happening? What can I do?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using either [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) for a very simple install. Anaconda brings all needed packages with it.

With Miniconda I would recommend to create an environment:

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
```

activate it:

```
conda activate py36
```

and install your packages:

```
(py36) conda install numpy scipy pandas statsmodel
```